# orbeon Field Validation bugs

Tags: validation, orbeon

I am using a xforms:bind to do field validation for a year field. the code is at below:

```
<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('application-instance')/academic/cert_ordinary/year" level="year-1" constraint="if (string-length(.) &lt; 1  ) then . = . else . castable as xs:integer and string-length(.) = 4 "/>
```

while the UI code is below:

```
<xforms:repeat ref="instance('application-instance')/academic/cert_as" id="cert-as-repeat">
  <xforms:input ref="year" incremental="true" class="input_smaller">
    <xforms:alert level="year-1">Must be 4 digit year!</xforms:alert>                           
  </xforms:input>
</xforms:repeat>
```

the validation is working fine, but the problem is, when i add multiple row of data, the validation is not working if i insert some string into the year and then change it to number.

for example, after i put "test" for 3 rows of year, the alert will shown there but then i change it to "2014", the alert for 1 row will still remains there and wont go away.

is this a bug from orbeon? FYI i using the orbeon 4.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seem like i made a mistake in the if statement

```
constraint="if (string-length(.) &lt; 1  ) then true() else . castable as xs:integer and string-length(.) = 4"
```

this shd be the correct if statement.

thanks